# sed search and replace only before a char

Tags: regex, sed

Is there a way to use sed (with potential other command) to transform all the keys in a file that lists key-values like that :

```
a.key.one-example=a_value_one
a.key.two-example=a_value_two
```

and I want that

```
A_KEY_ONE_EXAMPLE=a_value_one
A_KEY_TWO_EXAMPLE=a_value_two
```

What I did so far :
`sed -e 's/^[^=]*/\U&/'`

it produced this :

```
A.KEY.ONE-EXAMPLE=a_value_one
A.KEY.TWO-EXAMPLE=a_value_two
```

But I still need to replace the "." and "-" on left part of the "=". I don't think it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done very easily done in `awk`. `awk` is the better tool IMHO for this task, it keeps it simple and easy.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} {$1=toupper($1);gsub(/[.-]/,"_",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

***Simple explanation:***

- Make field separator and output field separator  as `=`
- Then use `awk`'s default function named `toupper` which will make $1(first field) upper case and save it into $1 itself.
- Using `gsub` to substitute `.` OR `-` with `_` in $1 as per requirement.
- use `1` which is idiomatic way to print a line in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;y/.-/__/;s/.*/\U&/;G;s/=.*=/=/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line.

Translate `.` and `-` to `_`.

Capitalize the whole line.

Append the copy.

Remove the centre portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
sed ':a;s/^\([^=]*\)[.-]\([^=]*\)/\U\1_\2/g;ta' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `:a` - sets an `a` label
- `s/^\([^=]*\)[.-]\([^=]*\)/\U\1_\2/g` - replaces `^\([^=]*\)[.-]\([^=]*\)` pattern that matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\([^=]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than `=`
  - `[.-]` - a dot or hyphen
  - `\([^=]*\)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any zero or more chars other than `=`
- `ta` - jumps back to `a` label position upon successful replacement

  and replaces with Group 2 + `_` + Group 1

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/r2BijD):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='a.key.one-example=a_value_one
a.key.two-example=a_value_two'
sed ':a;s/^\([^=]*\)[.-]\([^=]*\)/\U\1_\2/g;ta' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
A_KEY_ONE_EXAMPLE=a_value_one
A_KEY_TWO_EXAMPLE=a_value_two
```

Comment: Why use `g` option with `t` label branching? It makes no sense.

Comment: @HatLess I agree, but I am always reproached for not using `g` in these cases by other SO users.